# Powershell v3 - Datable usage in Workflow

Tags: powershell, workflow, powershell-3.0

I'want to use dataTable in a PowerShell v3 workflow to populate a database, with some data.

The fact that we can't call method in a workflow prevent me to add the column to the dataTable.

```
$dataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable
$col1 = New-Object -TypeName system.Data.DataColumn -Parameter colDate,([datetime])
$dataTable.Columns.add($col1)
```

Ce third line is forbidden in a PS Workflow. It seems that I must use InlineScript{}.
But if I tried this it generate again an error (expression forbidden in Using expression) :

```
$dataTable = InlineScript { $using:dataTable.Columns.add($using:col1}
```

So how can'I add the column to the dataTable with those constraints ?

Thanks in advance for your help.